# Based on repeated calls to the sleep() function, what is the minimum amount of time that the given code will require to execute?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to figure out 2 questions- Firstly, I would like to know the minimum amount of time that the following code will require to execute, given the repeated calls to the sleep() function. My given code is:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import *
root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root, width=600, height=400)
canvas.pack()

a = canvas.create_line(10, 50, 20, 60, fill="#0000AA", width=2)
for i in range (0, 500):
  canvas.move(a, 1, 0.2)
  root.update()
  sleep(0.02)
```

At first I thought maybe it was 0.02, but that answer seems blatantly obvious and does not take into mind the loop. So I am a bit confused.

Also, why is it that the actual execution of the above code will take longer than the time calculated according to the calls to the sleep() function?

Comment: The other called functions have work to do, too.

Comment: Each line of code has a large mountain of functions underneath it, so executing two different lines at the same time is impossible!

It happens differently if we want to fix the execution time of other lines. The state of the processor is not constant, so the same line can have different (almost always) execution times.

Answer (score 1):

So the sleep is going to consume 10 seconds (500 * 0.02) and the other calls `canvas.move()` and `root.update()` both are going to take some time.  Probably not a ton, another second or so.

The easiest thing to do is just time the whole thing by wrapping your code in some timing code:

```
import datetime 

start = datetime.datetime.now()
# your code here 
end = datetime.datetime.now() 

print(end-start)
```